# Error: self signed certificate while trying to migrate to heroku

Tags: heroku, migration

Before I was getting a no pg_hba.conf error so I change around my postgrator config around to try and fix that.

Currently it looks like:

```
require('dotenv').config();

  const postString = process.env.DATABASE_URL + "?sslmode=require";

  module.exports = {
    "migrationsDirectory": "migrations",
    "driver": "pg",
    "connectionString": postString,
    ssl: {
      rejectUnauthorized: false
    }
  }
```

And it gives me the following error:

```
Error: self signed certificate
```

Now I'm not sure what to do.

Comment: Did you get this figured out? I've been having the same error last couple days (even had ' no pg_hba.conf error ' first). Looks like you're using Postgrator?